# libctransformers.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: dockerfile, langchain, llama

I'm trying to run a Docker container that is powering my web app on an Ubuntu ec2 machine.

When i launch the docker run command, the app is correctly opening up on the 8000 port. However, on the main page of the app, the following error is displayed:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ctransformers/lib/basic/libctransformers.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I went to the specified directory and I can see that the folder site-packages is not there. I have the dist-packages folder that however does not contain the specified file.

My docker file contains the following:

FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --default-timeout=100 future

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["chainlit", "run", "model.py"]

I cannot understand what's going wrong. Can you help me out?
Thank you

Comment: Could you share the content of files `requirements.txt` and `model.py` to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in to this identical issue. Dockerfile using Ubuntu 22.04, building for ARM.

Remove ctransformers from your requirements.txt, and in your dockerfile, have this separate line:

`RUN pip3 install ctransformers --no-binary ctransformers`

Once built, you'll find the error of not finding `libctransformers.so` is resolved, (even though despite it being findable in the filesystem manually).

I'm still researching the "why", and am open to any reasoning.